# Is there a name for functions that are only called by an overloaded version of that function?

Tags: c++

Some times I see this design paradigm where a function calls its overload, and that overload is never called anywhere else, such as...

```
void doStuff(int stuff)
{
   doStuff(stuff, m_things); // the only place this overload is ever called
}
```

or alternatively as part of a class where one version is public and the other version is private (not an overload exactly but the repeated use of the function names makes clear its relationship to the first example)

```
class GreatExample
{
public:
   void doIt();
   // some other methods...
private:
   void _doIt();
   // some data memebers...
}

// later in UsefulProgram.cpp...

void GreatExample::doIt()
{
   // useful computer things...
   _doIt();
}
```

Is there a specific name for this sort of function? Encapsulation comes to mind but it seems a bit too broad a term as there's a name for everything in c/c++. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you should probably update your user description :D , lest someone thinks you owe them money. As for the question, I don't think I've heard a special term for this pattern.

Comment: If there was an internal class rather than a function I'd say "pImpl idiom" but I don't think you can really put a formal name on this. Perhaps just "delegation"

Comment: I call them **thunk** functions, usually for when an API changes and I want backwards compatibility, or because I dislike default parameter values in a public API (because that bakes the value into the caller at the callsite, making the code have tighter coupling due to that dependency).  But if it is the only place the other function is called, then it would be a public API thunk to an internal implementation function.  Not sure if there is a *term* for that.

Comment: I'm partly tempted to suggest it's a use for the term, "delegate," but that's normally used in a different, rather more specialized, sense in C++. Oops - sorry, @Tim, missed your comment at first.

Comment: Call it *compatibility burden*

Comment: Ok these are all helpful, even knowing that there isn't a name per say is useful to know. Thanks!